# Who are Los Aterradores?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, campaign-settings

*Impossible Lands* (pg.226) shows three key factions in the Mana Wastes. One of them is Los Aterradores. Who is this faction?

I didn't see any substantive description of them in the rest of the section.

They are mentioned a few times in passing. Apparently the necromancer Alemayehu's crew is a subset or affiliate (pg.236). Blooming Chaos is a member (pg. 234).

So who are they?

Comment: No actual in-game lore info, but that's Spanish for "The terrifying". Sounds like a gang.

Answer (score 5):

## Seemingly a Nomadic Wizard Gang

This is derived from the [Wild Magic rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1879) in Impossible Lands (the book) - I've bolded key parts below.

> In extreme contrast are those who see the erratic patterns of magic within the Wastes as an opportunity. To the combat mages of the **nomadic wizard gang** led by Velasco Cueto, a dearth of magic is a chance to prove oneself in other arenas, such as alchemical crafting and more conventional forms of combat. For members of Los Aterradores, **it's also** one of the most strenuous tests for their **strange, eldritch creations**. One such innovation is **condensed mana**: powerful and unstable magical miasmas collected into a throwable form. Some, **like Velasco** and the Sixfold Repentance, have banned this creation, as they understand the creation process and its immense dangers to both creators and the already fragile ecosystem of the Wastes. Only **the wizards of Los Aterradores** create condensed mana, and only the most daring deploy them in combat.

Notably, Pathfinder Wiki doesn't have an entry on Los Aterradores, which means they're likely to have been invented recently. Given they're lack of reference in other things, I'd expect them to *only* appear in the Impossible Lands book so far, and this [Reddit Q&A with one of the Paizo Developers](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder2e/comments/z69kz2/comment/iy1gnzn/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) seems to confirm my suspicion there (as well as the Spanish origins of the name).

So, some deductions of the above paragraph tells us a few things about "The Terrifying" (the English translation, apparently? Although "The Terrors" seems more fitting).

- They are a nomadic wizard gang! (They are put in the same category as Velasco Cueto's gang)
- They create "strange, eldritch" things, one of which is "[condensed mana](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1802)".
- They have a reckless disregard for the stability of the Wastes; this is in comparison to other gangs, so they seem quite reckless - they deploy weapons banned by other *gangs*.

And... that's it.

Given the above, I picture them as a sort of fantasy wizard-alchemist version of a Mad Max gang. Indeed, given their recklessness, and the creative liberty given to GMs by the (likely somewhat intentional) sparse description of them, that is the direction this GM would take with the faction.